# Mac OS X Speech Won't Work

Tags: macos, mac, speech

Let's say i'm reading a book online. I wouldn't want to read i would use the Speech Feature by Apple. I open Safari, read a book, I select all using CMD+A and i right click and start the speech. I updated Safari for some new stuff and i wanted to test out the speech. It won't work for some reason.

Can anyone help me out?

Im using Mac OS X Mountain Lion (10.8.3), Updated Safari to 7.0.1

Comment: Try selecting a smaller quantity to speak — selecting all may take a very long processing time.

Comment: Ok i will do this, i'll do little parts while reading, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out your speech and dictation settings. Ensure that you have the language downloaded and enabled. You can access this through system preferences (Apple on top right > System Preferences > Speech and Dictation)

Answer (score -1):

Default short-cut is Option+Esc but you can change it something more convenient for you.  Be sure to chose a system voice other than default which have been improved to be more natural.